# To perform two way data binding in tree component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using a **tree** component in my project.When i select the **child element**(i,e HTML5) from the **parent element** (i,e Web Technologies).The selected child **(HTML5)** element is displayed on the input field as shown in below image.

[image]

Along with this i want to assign some values to **child element** and display it in on other div at the same time when **child element** (HTML)is selected.As shown in below image.

[image]

Here i need to perform two way data binding.I got resources for **select component** but unable get it for **tree component**.Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8zdkh-qvzqmf?file=app/chips-autocomplete-example.html) link.

Comment: Can you please add more details what is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: Here on selecting/clicking the child element(i,e HTML5). I need to display some data(dummy) outside the tree component,Just to show that i have selected HTML5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8zdkh-cviy9i)

HTML:

```
<div class="text-inside">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Select offering" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" (focus)="showDropDown = true">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" *ngIf="showDropDown">
        <!-- Leaf node -->
        <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodePadding (click)="selectedItem = node.item;showDropDown = false;">
            <button mat-icon-button disabled></button> {{node.item}}
        </mat-tree-node>

        <!-- expandable node -->
        <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding>
            <button mat-icon-button [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.filename" (click)="loadChildren(node)" matTreeNodeToggle>
                <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
                  {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
                </mat-icon>
              </button> {{node.item}}
        </mat-tree-node>

        <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: isLoadMore">
            <button mat-button (click)="loadMore(node.loadMoreParentItem)">
                Load more...
              </button>
        </mat-tree-node>
    </mat-tree>
    <div [hidden]="!selectedItem || showDropDown">
        <div>
            List Of Guides {{selectedItem}}:
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let li of Guides">{{li}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDITS:**

```
<div [hidden]="!selectedItem || showDropDown">
        <div>
            List Of Guides {{selectedItem}}:
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let li of getGuides(selectedItem)?.data">{{li}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

TS:

```
Guides: Array<any> = [
    {name: 'css3' , data:  ['Tutorial Css3', 'Videos Css3' , 'Questions Css3']},
    {name: 'HTML5' , data :  ['Tutorial HTML5', 'Videos HTML5', 'Questions HTML5']},

    {name: 'Javascript', data:  ['Tutorial Javascript', 'Videos Javascript', 'Questions Javascript']},

  ]
  hideGuide: boolean = false;

  getGuides(selectedItem){
    return this.Guides.find(data => data.name == selectedItem )
  }
```

Comment: How can i assign different values for another child element, for example if i select **css** i want to display another set of values.

Comment: Create Array Of Gudides with keys :

  Guides: Array<any> = [
    {'css': ['Tutorial', 'Videos', 'Questions']}
  ]

Comment: I tried but the output is coming like this `[object Object]`

Comment: Sorry to say this,I am unable to extract the object.

Comment: Working Fine Check Demo

Comment: I got it, Thank you so much.